# JavaScript Framework Order?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, frameworks

First post on this site, so bear with me.

I got a decent handle on jQuery, but then I tried to jump to Backbone.js and it was a little bit over my head. And I decided that I want to ease my way into it by slowly working up.

What order did YOU learn the Frameworks in?

Comment: jQuery -> jQuery UI -> Bootstrap -> Angular.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Unfortunately this kind of question is off topic here. Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise. You can read more here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Sorry about that. I'll use my better judgment in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before learning jQuery, you can check these W3Schools tutorials:
http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/default.asp
http://www.w3schools.com/js/

A good resource for learning jQuery is on the jQuery Learning Center site: http://learn.jquery.com/. Especially, I would recommend you the JavaScript 101 Chapter for the beginning: http://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/